# How do I find text across many open buffers?

Tags: buffers, search

Lets say I have 10 buffers open, and I want to find all occurrences of `blah` in all 10 buffers. How would I do this?

Answer (score 51):

Sticking to built-in Emacs commands, you can use [`multi-occur`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Repeating-Search.html#index-multi_002doccur-872) or [`multi-occur-in-matching-buffers`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Repeating-Search.html#index-multi_002doccur_002din_002dmatching_002dbuffers-873) (`M-x multi-occur- TAB RET`). `multi-occur` gives you fine control by prompting for each buffer to use, but it's tedious. `multi-occur-in-matching-buffers` lets you enter a regexp to match file names (it only searches in buffers that are visiting files); enter `.` as the file regexp to search in all buffers that are visiting a file.

There are also functions for incremental search across a list of buffers or files, but they're tedious like `multi-occur` as they require listing the buffers or files one by one.

To search in all the files in a directory, or files matching certain patterns, whether they're open or not, you can use [`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html#index-grep-2555). There are variants `rgrep` and `grep-find` to search subdirectories recursively.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `.` is the regular expression to match all files.

Answer (score 17):

`swiper-all` from the [swiper package](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) provides a tool for doing this. It's even incremental, so it updates as you type.

[image]

Comment: this is great ! nice find

Answer (score 12):

This can be done with [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) via the command `helm-multi-occur`.  You can install helm from [melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/getting-started) and then call the command as follows:

```
M-x helm-multi-occur RET M-a RET
```

This will open `helm-multi-occur` and then select all buffers. Instead of using `M-a` to mark all buffers, you can optionally select the buffers of interest one at a time. Navigate up and down the list with `C-n` and `C-p` and mark buffers with `C-SPC`.  Once all of the buffers are marked, press `RET` to accept the marked buffers and start searching.

If you add the following to your init file:

```
(require 'helm-regexp)
(eval-after-load "helm-regexp"
  '(setq helm-source-moccur
    (helm-make-source "Moccur" 'helm-source-multi-occur :follow 1)))

;; (source: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14726601)
(defun my-helm-multi-occur-buffers ()
  "multi-occur in all buffers backed by files."
  (interactive)
  (helm-multi-occur
   (delq nil
     (mapcar (lambda (b)
           (when (buffer-file-name b) (buffer-name b)))
         (buffer-list)))))
```

You can then bind the command `my-helm-multi-occur-buffers` to do a multi-occur in all buffers that are backed by files.

Comment: You might also want to look at `helm-swoop` package in MELPA. It provides this functionality and allows quick editing of the results as well.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to what others have mentioned - here are two other resources for this.

1. `M-x multi-isearch-buffers` or `M-x multi-isearch-buffers-regexp` (vanilla Emacs) - Incremental search across multiple buffers.
2. If you use [**Icicles**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can use [`icicle-search`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) (or `icicle-occur`, or any number of other `icicle-search` specializations) to search across multiple files or buffers.

(In addition to searching and replacing across arbitrary **buffers**, there are of course commands that do that across multiple **files**.  Others have mentioned `grep`, for instance. And there is of course `A` in Dired.  But you did not ask about searching files.)

Answer (score 9):

You can use `ibuffer` mode to mark the buffers you would like to search. Call `ibuffer-do-isearch` (bound to `M-s a C-s` by default) to search for text, or `ibuffer-do-isearch-regexp` if you need to search for a regular expression.

If you aren't familiar with `ibuffer`, fire it up and take a look at the Mark menu to see all the ways you can choose a set of buffers on which to operate.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way with helm: `M-x helm-mini M-a C-s blah`. After invoking `helm-mini`, `M-a` will mark all opening buffers then `C-s blah` will do multi occur on marked buffers.

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla Emacs this exact sequence will find "blah" in any buffer:
`C-u M-x multi-occur-in-matching-buffers RET . RET blah RET`

To give it a better name and save a few keystrokes each time you use it, you can add a function like this to your config:

```
(defun search-all-buffers (regexp)
  (interactive "sRegex: ")
  (multi-occur-in-matching-buffers "." regexp t))
```

Comment: Isn't this information already in Gilles' answer?

Comment: @JeanPierre No, Gilles answer is missing a key part and has a bunch of irrelevant parts. This is the correct answer to the question that was asked. It finds "blah" in all open buffers regardless of wether they are attached to a file or not.

Answer (score 1):

I love `find-name-dired` for searching multiple files in emacs.  It's great if you only want to search your code files.

```
M-x find-name-dired
Find-name (directory): ~/code  <path at the top of your project> [RET]
Find-name (filename wildcard): *.[ch] <wildcard to select the files to include> [RET]
```

It opens a buffer called `*Find*`.  Put your cursor in the top left corner and hit `m`.  That will mark all the files listed.  You can hit `m` by each file you want.

Then there are two very useful functions.

```
'A' will give you a regex prompt that will pull up a list of matches.
'Q' is a global search and replace.
'h' will give you the help doc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, a solution using helm-mode is with `helm-swoop`.

Use

```
M-x helm-swoop RET
```

then, for searching in all open buffers, type

```
M-i
```

then, just type `blah` to search it in all buffers. On a different window will show all occurrences.

Alternatively, you can just type

```
M-x helm-multi-swoop
```

then, mark all buffers you wish to search with `M-SPC` or `C-SPC`, press `RET` and search for `blah`.