# Highlight a pattern in a buffer

Tags: search

I use C-s to search a pattern in a buffer. Then when I move the cursor, the highlighted matches lose highlight. Can I keep highlights however I move my cursor, or even edit the buffer?

What about when I search using regex?

Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of ways of doing it, search here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightTemporarily for something that appeals to you.

Comment: See the isearch variable `lazy-highlight-cleanup`:  *Controls whether to remove extra highlighting after a search.  If this is `nil`, extra highlighting can be "manually" removed with `lazy-highlight-cleanup`.*

Comment: [Related](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3243/115). There's also an `hl-anything` package available on MELPA.

Answer (score 5):

There's some built-in highlighting functionality bound to key sequences starting with `M-s h`. To see them all, type `M-s h C-h` to read about the `Global Bindings Starting With M-s h`.

The specific functionality you want is bound to `M-s h r`, `highlight-regexp`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using lazy highlight in your .emacs

```
(setq lazy-highlight-cleanup nil)
```

Comment: Yes, but this is a user option, so you might consider using `M-x customize-option`. Also, `lazy-highlight-cleanup` is a command, which you can use to remove the highlighting on demand at any time.