# highlight-regexp in multiple buffers

Tags: regular-expressions, faces

`highlight-regexp` is pretty amazing, but when I run it manually by `M-x highlight-regexp RET f?o RET 'someface` it only applies the highlight to the current buffer.  How can I apply a highlight to multiple buffers?

Similarly I would like to automatically highlight tabs in all files with a nasty face as I am allergic to them. Can I put something in my init.el to do that?

Comment: Are you sure you need to highlight tabs with `highlight-regexp` or other method would be acceptable? Do you want to highlight them always or temporarily?

Comment: Another method would be welcome, too.  I would also like to permanently highlight trailing whitespace in every buffer I have open, which I have been doing with highlight-regexp.

Comment: For tabs I'd look at whitespace mode, which can can be configured to highlight various kinds of whitespace.  You can also configure Emacs to never insert tabs or to replace them with spaces...

Comment: OK thanks.  But I'd still like to know how to `highlight-regexp` in all buffers at once.

Comment: Very closely related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3202/115

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Run `M-x ibuffer` to show all open buffers.
- Press <kbd>m</kbd> to mark buffers of interest (or one of the other more interesting marking commands).
- Press <kbd>E</kbd> to evaluate a lisp form in each marked buffer, for example,

  ```el
  (highlight-regexp "regexp-custard" 'hi-yellow)
  ```

You can save the patterns for a particular file with `hi-lock-write-interactive-patterns` (Default binding: `M-s h w`).

More generally, if you *always* want to highlight the same regexps across a range of files you could call `highlight-regexp` from a mode hook or `find-file-hook`.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know about this 'eval' feature in 'ibuffer'!

Answer (score 5):

You can solve all your problems with help of built-in minor mode called
`whitespace-mode`. This mode can be set up to highlight lines that are too
long as well as all sorts of normally “invisible” characters.

Here is basic setup that will highlight lines longer 80 characters and tabs:

```el
(setq
 whitespace-line-column 80
 whitespace-style       '(face lines-tail tabs))
```

To enable it you can use one of these methods:

```el
(whitespace-mode 1)        ; enable locally
(global-whitespace-mode 1) ; enable everywhere
```

To find out more about things the mode can highlight, see documentation of
`whitespace-style` variable: <kbd>C-h v whitespace-style RET</kbd>.

Comment: My bad for asking two questions at once :(  This is a great answer for the 2nd one.

Answer (score 3):

- You can use library [**Highlight**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) (code: [`highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el)) to do what you want.  Command `hlt-highlight-regexp-region-in-buffers` highlights matches for a regexp across a set of buffers.
- You can use library [**Highlight Chars**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowWhiteSpace#HighlightChars) (code: [`highlight-chars.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight-chars.el)) to highlight any character in a single buffer or all buffers.  Command `hc-toggle-highlight-tabs`, for example, highlights `TAB` characters using face `hc-tab`, which you can of course customize.

Comment: So it looks like it's not possible with the normal highlight-* commands then.  Thanks for the recommendation(s).

Comment: @MatthewGilliard: I didn't say that, and I don't know that. Someone else can speak to that. I use the libraries I cited, and have been doing so since long before vanilla Emacs had any such highlighting commands - before standard library `hi-lock.el` existed.