# Jump to word in another window

Tags: isearch

I went from this issue [Highlighting text in open (displayed) buffers/windows — searching for text from one buffer in another](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/highlighting-text-in-open-displayed-buffers-windows-searching-for-text-from).

I would like to write the function for these commands to jump to word in another window: `C-s C-w C-x o C-s C-s C-x o`.

This is my code that doesn't work:

```
 (defun jump-word-other-window ()
   (interactive)
   (save-excursion
     (isearch-yank-word-or-char)
       (other-window 1)
       (isearch-forward)
       (isearch-repeat-forward)
        (other-window 1)))
```

How can I write this working keyboard combination in the function?

Comment: And the question is...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution.

```
(defun jump-word-other-window ()
  (interactive)
  (isearch-forward nil 1)
  (isearch-yank-word-or-char)
  (other-window 1)
  (isearch-repeat-forward)
  (isearch-exit)
  (other-window 1))
```

Comment: Accept your own answer once you're able to.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `save-excursion` documentation:

> Save point, and current buffer; execute BODY; restore those things.

No matter how many times `other-window` function is called point will remain where your function was invoked.